# How to Generate Swagger File For Azure Java Function

Tags: spring, api, azure-functions, swagger, azure-java-sdk

I Have Azure HttpTrigger Java functions(get, Post) Those are Working Fine in Postman but, as per the Client Requirement I need To create swagger UI file for all those functions(Java) i am searching Refference stuff from lastweek, stil i did not get it,So plese any one share/guide/help me

1. How to craete Azure HttpTriggerr Java function project with Springboot Application?
2. How to add Swagger Configuration to it?

Comment: Have you tried the creation of it in springboot, any errors got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How to craete Azure HttpTriggerr Java function project with Springboot Application?

Following this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/hello-spring-function-azure/hello-spring-function-azure/), created the Azure Functions Http Trigger in Spring boot.

1st Step is cloning the basic Function code of Sprint Boot Azure Functions Application.
[image]

Step 2: In pom.xml, you have to change these properties accordingly:

```xml
<functionResourceGroup>HariTestRG</functionResourceGroup>
<functionAppName>my-spring-function-app</functionAppName>
```

Step 3: Clean and build the packages `./mvnw clean package` and then run using the cmdlet `./mvnw azure-functions:run`

[image]

Next is to deploy the function code to Azure Function App:

```
./mvnw azure-functions:deploy
```

**Result**:
[image]

[image]

> 2. How to add Swagger Configuration to it?

Go to the Azure Portal > Deployed Function App > Click on API Management on left Index > Import the Function App APIs in APIM Instance > Then you'll see the Open API Definition which generates the swagger UI file for all the functions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to generate swagger file for normal java functions(without springboot) because  all my functions are non springboot functions so now it is challenging me to switch and i don't know spring boot also.....

Comment: Please Raise the new question on which language you're trying to create the Azure Functions and generate the swagger file and what you have tried!